# How do I differentiate between IE versions 6 to 10 using IE CSS Hacks?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am working on a web design that uses Bootstrap and so I'm customizing the Bootstrap framework.
I have designed an element that because of lack of support for transitions in IE9, lack of support for some features like opacity and some others in IE8 and lack of support for box-sizing, correct position:absolute positioning and other problem, I need a way to differentiate  between IE versions right from CSS style sheets, because I'm customizing the Bootstrap framework, I prefer a single complete .css framework file so, here is the question:

**How do I differentiate between IE versions 6 to 10 using IE CSS Hacks on a single CSS role?**

Comment: You're supposed to ask it as a question and put that information in an answer..

Comment: OK! Thanks for your negative point! I was just sharing my experience! @Zenith

Comment: This is bad :(, this is why we have conditional stylesheets to target IE < 10 specifically.

Comment: Yes as per @Zenith comments this would probably be better presented as "How do I differentiate between IE versions", with your content in answer.  Also probably some additional explanation, particularly around IE8/IE9 differentiation, as what you are actually doing there seems unclear to giving the reader an idea as to WHY these differentiations work.

Comment: @Zenith I changed the post to question and answers. Your comment and the first downvote were submitted exactly at the same moment so I just thought that it were yuo. Thanks for your advice and sorry for my anger. :P ;)

Comment: @MikeBrant Thanks for your advice, that was a clever suggestion. I explained the difference in the comments for those 2 role values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hI was dealing with IE and needed to target every particular version separately and after some testing came up with this css:

```
body {
    background-color:#0099CC; /* For Other standard browsers */
    background-color: #FFFF00\9; /* For IE9 (Note: There is "NO" space before \9) */
    background-color: #00E300 \9; /* For IE8 (Note: There is "ONE" space before \9) */
    *background-color: #FF9900; /* For IE7 */
    _background-color: #FF0000; /* For IE6 */
}
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
    body{
        background-color:#FF99CC; /* For IE10 */
    }
}
```

These codes make IE 6 to 10 show different colors for body background.

I used IE 10.0.9200.16384's "Browser Modes" for testing the IE 7 to 10 and "IETester" program for IE 6 testing and they worked like a charm.

Shared my experience here for your use and if you tested them and had successful or unsuccessful results please submit your experience here to share with others.

Thanks.

Comment: These don't validate, as they're hacks, the proper way to do it is to implement this : **[How To Create an IE-Only Stylesheet](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)**

Comment: Yes they don't but there are many of them in grid frameworks like Bootstrap and so. So not as the best solution but as a way of doing thing to get them right, it could be a solution.

Comment: seriously you should find a new job if you are coding for IE6

Comment: @ScottSimpson not that I'm coding for IE6, I'm the SEO of my own company, my developers may need to change their job because there are customers that expect IE6 to work properly beside the modern browsers. ;)